# User mapping is not working in OpsHub Migration Utility

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

I was mapping all the users. Migration done successfully to Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online). But its still migration doesn't have changeset with corresponding user name. It displays only with who is running migration tool.

Can you help me on this ?

Comment: Are you using the free version?

Comment: Yes. I am using the free version

Comment: Free version does not support this feature, refer to the answer from OpsHub for details.

Answer (score 1):

In the free version of OpsHub Migration Utility, the user mapping is getting used only for migrating the values of user type fields for work items. There is no user impersonation available in the Free version. User impersonation is only available in the commercial version of utility only.